# Toggle text with function called with onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, toggle

my question is a short one but I couldn't figure it out by myself. I've got a function like -> http://jsfiddle.net/gtU56/ . I'm calling a javascript-function with an event-listener(onclick) in my html-code. The function itself is more complex but I need the last snippet. By clicking 'Show More' the text should change. Why won't the text change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `toggleText` function isn't available when the html code is rendered.

In other words the function isn't set until the page is ready so the `onclick` function doesn't reference anything.

Either have the function like here http://jsfiddle.net/gtU56/2/

or have it in the head of the page because its needs to be ready immediately

If you want it to wait for the `ready` state you can do the following and remove the `onclick` action all together

http://jsfiddle.net/gtU56/7/

```
$(".text").click(function()
{                     
   $(".text").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
toggleText = function () {
    $('.text').toggle();
}
```

check here http://jsfiddle.net/gtU56/3/

Answer (score 1):

It's because of how you're loading the function. Switch it from onLoad to no wrap (head) and it works fine.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gtU56/4/)**

Using jsFiddle's onLoad wraps your function in a window.onload call like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
function toggleText() {
$('.text').toggle();
}
});//]]> 
</script>
```

While no wrap (head) just adds it normally like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function toggleText() {
$('.text').toggle();
}
//]]> 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are already claiming having `jquery`, you need not use inline javascript. try this

```
var elems = $('.text');
elems.click(function(){
  elems.toggle(); 
});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gtU56/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.text').click(function() {
  $('.text').toggle('slow', function() {
    // do your animation..
  });
});
```

​
[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fosterz/GDpKU/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution - http://jsfiddle.net/gtU56/6/

You need to first make sure that the function is registered after page load.  Then, bind a `click` event to the div.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

First you should organize you jQuery code like this:

```
$.(document).ready(function() {
// enter jQuery code here
});
```

Otherwise you're accessing a not completly loaded html document.

Also, you don't need the event-listener if you are using jQuery.

This should work for you:

```
$.(document).ready(function() {
   $('.text').click(function() {
      $(this).toggle();
   });
});
```

Comment: "Otherwise you're accessing a not completly loaded html document." Actually the fiddle does that with the select boxes on the side. That is why the code was not running.

Answer (score 0):

Is very easy. You can use ID or CLASS.

```
onclick="$('NAME ID or CLASS').toggle(ANIMATION or DURATION);"


<div>
    <div class="text" onclick="$('.text2').toggle(400);">Show More</div>
    <div class="text2" style="display:none">Show Less</div>
</div>
```